# How to get the exact time of all MIDI beats and measure starts?

Tags: python, midi, mido, midi-instrument

I have a MIDI file that contains an orchestra piece I wrote, and I want to create punches and streamers for it. If you don't know what that is, that's okay — essentially the gist is I need to know the exact time value that each beat and measure start are on.

i.e. A measure starts at 0:03.35, 0:06.64, 0:10.52; there is a beat at 0:01.64, 0:02.32, etc. (this would probably be in milliseconds)

I know how to use Mido in Python to extract the MIDI commands send through the file (tempo change at x time, etc), but I have found no way to get the exact timing of each beat or measure start. It would be difficult to manually track each beat by keeping track of the tempo at x time because I have some ritardandos and accelerandos that send tempo change commands at alarming rates.

Is there any way (a library, different method) to find the exact millisecond time value that each beat and measure start occurs?